# How to turn a dataframe of two columns, where each row represents a pair of friends id, into a data with id and all their friends in the one row?

Tags: apache-spark, hive, presto

Data example:

col1  col2

```
id1   id2
id2   id3
id1   id4
id3   id4
```

Output:

col1 col2

```
id1  id2, id4
id2  id1, id3
id3  id2
id4  id1, id3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    val df = List(("id1", "id2"),
    ("id2", "id3"),
    ("id1", "id4"),
    ("id3", "id4")
  ).toDF("col1", "col2")


 df.groupBy('col1).agg(array_join(collect_set('col2), ",").as("col2"))
    .union(
      df.groupBy('col2).agg(array_join(collect_set('col1), ",").as("col2"))
    )
    .groupBy('col1).agg(array_join(collect_set('col2), ",").as("col2")).show()
```

output:

```
+----+-------+
|col1|   col2|
+----+-------+
| id3|id2,id4|
| id1|id2,id4|
| id2|id1,id3|
| id4|id1,id3|
+----+-------+
```

Hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

Another idea is to collect in a list and after apply an scala mkString 
So the first query is

```
select col1, collect_list(col2) as c from test group by col1
```